# How to run c++ Files using g++ and Cmake?

Tags: cmake, g++

I am using Header Only Libraries. The libraries are included through Cmake. I am using the g++ Compiler.
Now what I am looking for is to compile the c++ source files via windows cmd. In this moment i am using clion to compile.

Does anyone know how to compile the source files?
If i am compiling the files without cmake , I am getting errors because the program cannot find the libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You do not run a source file, you run an executable produced by a compiler from  source file(s)

If you are under a Linux for instance enter the path(s) where the libraries are through the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

---

[edit after your remark]

> I mean compile

To indicate to `g++` where the library are to link use the option `-L` followed by the path of a directory where the libraries are. If your libraries are on different directories use several time the option, one per directory

Comment: Sorry yea, I mean compile. I am using windows.

Comment: @IsoFunCode use the option `-L` of g++ to indicate the path where the libraries are, if you have several paths use several times the option `-L`, one per path

Comment: I have the path of libraries as Enviroment variable. Can I use g++  -L LIB_A_INCLUDE_PATH.... is that correct?

Comment: @IsoFunCode no after `-L` a path is required, a path of a directory containing libs, not the pathname of a lib